Does sequential compactness guarantee every convergent subsequence in S converges to a point in S
Let $E,F \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be compact sets. Define
$$ d(E,F) := \inf_{x \in E, y \in F} |x - y|$$
Prove that there exists points $\hat{x} \in E,\hat{y} \in F$ such that
$$ d(E,F) = |\hat{x} - \hat{y}|$$
Proof:
$$\inf_{x \in E, y \in F} |x - y| = \inf \{|x - y|, x \in E, y \in F\} = |\hat{x} - \hat{y}|$$
It remains to show that $\hat{x} \in E$ and $\hat{y} \in F$. Since we are considering the infimum, there exists a sequence $c_n = |a_n - b_n|$ where $(a_n) \in E$ and $(b_n) \in F$ and $(a_n) \rightarrow \hat{x}$ and $(b_n) \rightarrow \hat{y}$.
Since $E$ is compact, by definition of sequential compactness, every sequence in $E$ has a convergent subsequence which converges to a point also in $E$.

$(a_n)$ is a sequence in E by definition of $(a_n)$

$(a_n)$ is a trivial subsequence of $(a_n)$

$(a_n)$ is a convergent subsequence as implied by use of $\inf$

By 1), 2) and 3), $(a_n)$ must converge to a point in $E$, namely $\hat{x}$. Thus $\hat{x} \in E$.


Is step 4 correct use of the definition of sequential compactness? Are we allowed to say that if a set $E$ is compact, then every convergent subsequence in $E$ converges to a point also in $E$?
Or is the definition implying only existence? That there, in fact, may be convergent subsequences in $E$ that converge to a point not in E?

A compact set in a in a Hausdorff space is closed. Ie. $E$ and $F$ are closed, therefore any convergent sequence of $E$ converges to a point in $E$.

Sorry, I'm not very familiar with Hausdorff spaces? I'm very new to analysis

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem

Okay I've seen Heine-Borel. So we only need to know that a set is closed and bounded in order to guarantee that every convergent subsequence in a set converges to a point in that set?

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is true. Compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are those sets which are both closed and bounded. And if a set is closed, then any convergent sequence of the set converges to a point in the set.

I see! Thank you!

How does the use of $\inf$
imply that $(a_n)$
is a convergent sequence? You should use sequential compactness to say there is a subsequence of $(a_n)$
that converges to a point $\hat{x} \in E$
. See my answer below for a proof that there exists $\hat{x} \in E$ and $\hat{y} \in F$ such that $d(E,F)=|\hat{x}-\hat{y}|$.

Since $d(E,F)=\inf\{|x - y| : x \in E \text{ and } y \in F\}$, there is $(x_1,y_1) \in E \times F$ so that $d(E,F) \leq |x_1-y_1| < d(E,F) +1$. Moreover, there is $(x_2,y_2) \in E \times F$ so that $d(E,F) \leq |x_1-y_1| < d(E,F) +\frac{1}{2}$. And for each positive integer $n>2$, we may find $(x_n, y_n) \in E \times F$ so that $d(E,F) \leq |x_n-y_n| < d(E,F) +\frac{1}{n}$. Since $E$ is compact and $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $E$, there is a subsequence $\{x_{n_j}\}$ that converges to a point $\hat{x} \in E$. Since $F$ is compact and $\{y_{n_j}\}$ is a sequence in $F$, there is a subsequence $\{y_{n_{j_k}}\}$ that converges to a point $\hat{y} \in F$.
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. We may find $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $N_1\epsilon>2$. We may find $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|x_{n_j}-\hat{x} |<\epsilon/4$ whenever $j \geq N_2$. We may find $N_3 \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|y_{n_{j_k}}-\hat{y} |<\epsilon/4$ whenever $k \geq N_3$. Let $N=\max\{N_1, N_2, N_3\}$. Then $k \geq N$ implies that we have
\begin{align*}|\hat{x}-\hat{y}| &= |\hat{x}-x_{n_{j_k}}+x_{n_{j_k}}-y_{n_{j_k}}+y_{n_{j_k}}-\hat{y}| \\& \leq |\hat{x}-x_{n_{j_k}}|+|x_{n_{j_k}}-y_{n_{j_k}}|+|y_{n_{j_k}}-\hat{y}|
\\& < d(E,F)+\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Since $|\hat{x}-\hat{y}| \geq d(E,F)$, it follows that $|\hat{x}-\hat{y}| =d(E,F)$.

Some details: When $k \geq N_1$, we have $n_{j_k} \geq n_{j_{N_1}} \geq n_{N_1} \geq N_1$. So $\frac{1}{n_{j_k}} \leq \frac{1}{N_1}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ whenever $k \geq N_1$. When $k \geq N_2$, we have $j_k \geq j_{N_2} \geq N_2$. So $|x_{n_{j_k}}-\hat{x}|<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$ whenever $k \geq N_2$.
